# Rails Routing - Adding parameters to :resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got some routes defined as follows:

```
namespace :owners do
  resources :orders, only: [:show, :edit, :update] do              

    resources :bibles, only: [:update]
  end
end
```

Which creates all the nice routes you'd expect. One caveat: I'd like to add an additional parameter to the end of the `edit` route, to turn this

```
/owners/orders/:id/edit
```

into

```
/owners/orders/:id/edit/:another_parameter
```

What's the Railsy way to do this?

Comment: The :id/edit route implies that you are editing the entity with the given id. What you're proposing isn't RESTful, so there isn't really an official way to do this. Perhaps you could add more explanation of  you're trying to do and why you need the parameter?

Comment: The additional parameter mostly acts as a version number.

Comment: I think that you probably want a new model in here to represent the version of each order. Doing this you'd get more traditional routes along the lines of /owners/orders/:order_id/versions/:id/edit which is much more fitting with RESTful principles.

Comment: Will the call be routed to different controllers based on the value of `:another_parameter`?

Comment: @jvillian - Nope, same controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to achieve what you want

```
namespace :owners do
  resources :orders, only: [:show, :update] do
    member do
      get 'edit/:another_parameter', to: 'orders#edit'
    end
    resources :bibles, only: [:update]
  end
end
```

This will give you the following routes:

```
                   GET    /owners/orders/:id/edit/:another_parameter(.:format) owners/orders#edit
owners_order_bible PATCH  /owners/orders/:order_id/bibles/:id(.:format)        owners/bibles#update
                   PUT    /owners/orders/:order_id/bibles/:id(.:format)        owners/bibles#update
      owners_order GET    /owners/orders/:id(.:format)                         owners/orders#show
                   PATCH  /owners/orders/:id(.:format)                         owners/orders#update
                   PUT    /owners/orders/:id(.:format)                         owners/orders#update
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a routing problem on your hands since your call will always be going to the same controller.

I think all you want is an extra parameter passed to the controller which you do something like:

```
  edit_owners_orders_path(@order, another_parameter: 'foo')
```

This should generate something like:

```
  /owners/orders/:id/edit?another_parameter=foo
```

Then, in your controller, you should get parameters something like:

```
  {id: 1, another_parameter: 'foo'}
```

Some of the syntax may not be exactly correct. Apologies for that. But I believe this is a workable direction.